anyone has experience this?bulge on the ceiling but no sign of water leak..house is newly built
We just moved in 3 months ago and notice this linear bulge on the ceiling near the main entrance..no sign of water leak when touched. house is newly built.

What's above the bulge?

@SteveWellens master bedroom

Assuming no water, this is just drywall tape that’s been done wrong. Check your warranty terms (they might want to bundle punchlist items after a set timeframe) and take it up with the builder.

thank you. builder is dodgy and not responding..dbdrv might take time also..thinking to get this fixed and go to building insurance..

If you have a deductible, that will cost you more than having a drywall professional out to repair.
